# Data base abstraction

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I need some kind of abstraction for database in my Java application. I have mySQL database with all properties and internal application data, and a second one for result data. I need to create new tables and populate them. Tricky part is that second DB might be different per instance of application, so it either can be Oracle DB or postgreSQL. Does anyone know some kind of tool that allows me to write one version of SQL and it will translate it to specific dialect of DB? Can hibernate or spring data help me with this?
Thank you for answers

**Edit**
I need to execute query not related to any object, simply create table with dynamically generated name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Surely Hibernate (or any other JPA[1] implementation) would help you. JPA is an API that would allow you to map your Java beans to database table rows in an abstract logic, in which SQL may even not be involved at all.

JPA has its own JPQL[2] (a SQL-like, object oriented query language), which will translate to the specific dialect of the actual database you are using; and it has a Criteria API[3] which will let you query and retrieve data from the database using type-safe method calls.

1. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_JPA%3F
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language
3. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria

Comment: But can I create query that is not related to any object?

Comment: Yes, you can use JPQL to cerate queries not related to objects, such as aggregates (`count`, `group by`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

Of course hibernate can help you on this. And the best part is that you don't even have to write SQL queries(HQL or Criteria will do your job). Only thing is that u have to change the DB details (like driver class, driver and dialect etc for establishing the connection) while changing the DB instances.

Comment: @Wojciech Bugaj Do you also need to copy the database to a different DB server(like backup and restore)? What is the exact operation you want to do? Explain a bit more, so that it'll be easier to answer.

Comment: But can I create query that is not related to any object?